# How can i insert a variable value into a column of table using trigger and sequence for oracle 10g db

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert, sequence, batch-processing

Am developing an application which helps people plan there schedule.

Lets say i have a table called 'Plan_Table' in which there are columns like

```
id,user_name, timestamp,place,event,plan_number.
```

For each day, a person can insert many records depending on his activities. I want 'plan_number' column to be populated by a trigger. 
Suppose an user inserts five records at a time(in a batch). I want the plan_number field to be  inserted as

```
plan_1
plan_1
plan_1
plan_1
plan_1
```

if he comes up with another plan.. and does few inserts, lets say 3 this time... I want the plan_number field to be inserted as

```
plan_2
plan_2
plan_2
```

How to achieve this using trigger and sequence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the combination of the before statement level trigger for that table along with the global package variables and then use them in the Row Level trigger for that table. 
Hope it gives you a heads up with the above logic

Comment: I will let you know how it goes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
var_plan_number number := 0;
begin 
if :new.plan_number is null then
 select max(plan_number) into var_plan_number from plan_table where timestamp < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 5 --*some_treshold - ie 5 seconds* 
 and timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and timestamp > trunc(sysdate) and user_name = :new.user_name;
 --idea is to select max plan_number for current day and increment it by 1
 --treshold should be set to time, your script is able to process batch records

 var_plan_number := var_plan_number + 1;    
 :new.plan_number := var_plan_number;
end if;
```

that should do the trick...

Please consider this as a pseudo code, how your trigger should look like. There is no need for sequences.

Comment: Procedures are kind of new to me. Any how, appreciate it and work it out. Thank you @Peter Pivarc

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the definition of "at a time (in a batch)". It will be difficult to tell the trigger when one batch ends and when a new one begins. It is possible with package variables, but the most competent place is your application.

I'd create a sequence to generate the ids, but pick up the ids in your application and feed them directly to the INSERT statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myids;
CREATE TABLE plan_table(id int, user_name varchar2(30), mytimestamp, ...);
```

And in your code:

```
SELECT myids.nextval INTO myplanid FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO plan_table(myplanid, myuser_name, SYSTIMESTAMP, place1 ...);
INSERT INTO plan_table(myplanid, myuser_name, SYSTIMESTAMP, place2 ...);
INSERT INTO plan_table(myplanid, myuser_name, SYSTIMESTAMP, place3 ...); 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will try and work out with this approach

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers you provided me. You really let me think in a purely db perspective. 
As a web application developer, I thought, its a much better approach to use sequence/trigger to help me out with this problem. However, I found the solution from business logic of Application itself.

I am using Hibernate ORM for managing db tables. Hence i pulled out the max value of plan number using the following pieces of code.

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Mwwp_Plan.class).setProjection(Projections.max("plan_number"));
    Integer maxPlanNumber = (Integer) criteria.uniqueResult(); 
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println(maxPlanNumber);
    if(maxPlanNumber==null)
    {
        System.out.println("maxPlanNumber is null");
        maxPlanNumber = 0;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    System.out.println("maxPlanNumber:"+maxPlanNumber);
    return maxPlanNumber;
```

This is inside a function which my app uses to get the max(plan_number). If there is no plan_number in the table. It will give a default of 1.

Note: Mwwp_Plan is the name of table i used in my application.

Hence I achieved what i wanted.

Thanks for your help.